# Exclude all the records even if 1 value is null after left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables T1 and T2, I am doing a left join to check if matches in T1 has all rounds in T2. In this case only Round 2 is present, So I want to ignore this match since it did not have all the rounds present in T2 Table

T1

| T1.MatchID | T1.RoundID |
| --- | --- |
| Match 1 | Round 2 |
| Match 1 | Round 3 |
| Match 1 | Round 4 |

T2

| T2.MatchID | T2.RoundID |
| --- | --- |
| Match 1 | Round 2 |

Result after Left Join

| T1.MatchID | T1.RoundID | T2.MatchID | T2.RoundID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Match 1 | Round 2 | Match 1 | Round2 |
| Match 1 | Round 3 | Null | Null |
| Match 1 | Round 4 | Null | Null |

I want to exclude Match1 from my resultset since It did not have all the corresponding round in T2 Table.

Comment: What is a desired result when full match is detected?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the match from T2 table after joining the two tables by delete the row with T1.ROUNDID = T2.ROUNDID

like this below:

```sql
DELETE FROM RESULT WHERE T1.ROUNDID = T2.ROUNDID
```